Convert multiple files to .img
I was making a simple bootloader and kernel by following a tutorial,
I am using Windows and this is the makefile I am using:
setup:
     nasm src\boot\boot.asm -f bin -o build\boot.bin
     rename build\boot.bin main_floppy.img

run:
     qemu-system-i386 -fda build\main_floppy.img

However now I have multiple files. How can I merge both of them into a single .img file?
setup:
    nasm src\boot\boot.asm   -f bin -o build\boot.bin
    nasm src\kernel\main.asm -f bin -o build\kernel.bin
    rename build\boot.bin main_floppy.img
    // add kernel file somehow too? I am using Windows 

run:
     qemu-system-i386 -fda build\main_floppy.img


If you are not using a file system on disk and combining both files back to back so the bootloader is sector 0 and the kernel is in sector 1+ then I'd recommend using chrysocome DD: http://www.chrysocome.net/downloads/dd-0.6beta3.zip  . It works much like the Linux DD. You can also use Windows for something simple like this instead of DD. copy /b build\boot.bin+build\kernel.bin build\main_floppy.img Its hard to tell what your bootloader is doing without code but I assume it is simple and is reading the kernel from the setors right after the bootloader.

You would try to use something like Mkisofs, which creates an ISO image from files on disk. Rolling your own bootloader is difficult, and I would reccomend using GRUB to load your own OS, which you can couple with grub-mkrescue to create a ISO image.
Since you are looking to create a bootable floppy, this would be what you are looking for.
More details are on the OSDEV wiki page I linked.
